# C program runs as expected on System. But fails with seg fault on docker

Tags: c, docker, sockets, pointers, segmentation-fault

I am experiencing a situation where a C application runs as expected on my computer systems, but when I run it on docker, it fails.

Task: To extract the hostnames from the URLs and try to connect to them.

Reproduction:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<unistd.h>
#include<sys/socket.h>
#include<sys/types.h>
#include<netinet/in.h>
#include<arpa/inet.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <netdb.h>


char *A[] = {"opc.tcp://9d458cabf108:4840", "opc.tcp://a3d095bf8206:4840", "opc.tcp://0e624a01b720:4840"};
char *B[] = {};
char *C[] ={};
int size = sizeof(A)/sizeof(char *));

int find_ip_address(char *hostname, char *ip_address)
{
      struct hostent *host_name;
      struct in_addr **ipaddress;
      int count;
      if((host_name = gethostbyname(hostname)) == NULL)
      {
            herror("\nIP Address Not Found\n");
            return 1;
      }
      else
      {
            ipaddress = (struct in_addr **) host_name->h_addr_list;
            for(count = 0; ipaddress[count] != NULL; count++)
            {
                  strcpy(ip_address, inet_ntoa(*ipaddress[count]));
                  return 0;
            }
      }
      return 1;
}

int ret;

void socketCommunication(char *ip_address,char *hostname, int port){
     int clientSocket,ret;
    struct  sockaddr_in serverAddr;
    char buffer[1024];
 
    
    clientSocket = socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM ,0);
    if(clientSocket<0){
        printf("Error in connection \n");
        exit(1);
    }
    memset(&serverAddr,'\0',sizeof(serverAddr));
    serverAddr.sin_port = htons(port);
    serverAddr.sin_family=AF_INET;
    serverAddr.sin_addr.s_addr=inet_addr(ip_address);     
    ret = connect(clientSocket,(struct sockaddr*)&serverAddr,sizeof(serverAddr));
    if(ret<0){
        printf("\nLOOKS LIKE NETWORK CONNECTION HAS FAILED. HAVE A LOOK AT THE NETWORK CONNECTIVITY at host : %s\n",hostname);
        printf("\n----Updated Status Information----:\n");
        printf("Discovery URL : opc.tcp://%s:%d\n",hostname,port);
        printf("Status:CONNECTON TIMED OUT\n");
        printf("\n");
   
    }
  
}


int main(void) {
    printf("%d\n",size);
    for(int i=0;i<size;i++){
            int length = strlen(A[i]);

            B[i] = A[i] + 10;
            printf("Hostname without AA binding : %s\n", B[i]);

            char *p = strrchr(B[i], ':');
            int port = strtoul(p+1, NULL, 10);
            printf("Extracted port : %d\n",port);

            
            char *e = strchr(B[i],':');
            int index = e - B[i];
            printf("line 104 %s\n",e);
            printf("line 105 %d\n",index);

        //extracting hostname
            char *add = malloc(index);
            memcpy(add,B[i],index);
            memset(&B[i],'\0',sizeof(B[i]));

            printf("hostname: %s\n",add);

            if(i!=0){
                char ip_address[50];

                find_ip_address(add,ip_address);
                printf("IP address done\n");
       
                socketCommunication(ip_address,add,port);///,&B[i]);
            printf("communication done\n");
          
            }
            free(add);
            free(B[i]);
    }
}
```

This program works as expected.
On docker, it runs into the segmentation fault after working well for 2 URL's.

Any guidance here? Would be very grateful. Where could I be possibly going wrong?

Regards,
Rakshan

Comment: That almost certainly means you have bugs in your code resulting in Undefined Behaviour. UB means the result is unpredictable - it can seg fault, it can produce garbage values, it can even appear to "work" under some conditions. Here is one problem: `char *B[] = {};` That array is zero length. Accessing it like this `B[i] = A[i] + 10;` is UB.

Comment: @kaylum could you tell me how to access it otherwise? OR just a direction to the concept of it would be useful.. I am new to C. I just want to remove the initial "opc.tcp://" there

Comment: You need to declare a non-zero length array: `char *B[size];`. (No need to initialise as global variables are zeroed by default).

Comment: If you don't know the size of the arrays at compile-time, you need to use *dynamic allocation*, and *reallocation* as you add elements to the arrays. Any decent text-book should have a decent amount of information about it.

Comment: @kaylum, doing a char *B[]; issues a warning saying that it is assumed to have one element

Comment: @RakshanPremsagarKapikad Not sure what your point is. Ok, maybe it's one element and not zero like I said. But obviously still wrong isn't it? Have you tried `char *B[size];`?

Comment: @kaylum, currently I have a fixed size of A[], what if I do not know the size of A in real example? Could you tell me how to declare then?